# asp.net merging result of 2 database search in one gridview

Tags: sql, gridview, data-binding, datasource

I have 2 databases from 2 third party providers.
both database have a table with a common unique identifiers (UI).
I want to display  table1 of DB1 filters out by the result of a list of unique Identifier retrieved for DB2.

and display the result in gridview.

the initial idea was to insert db2 UI in a virtual table in DB1 and then the usual select db1.table1 - JOIN Virtualtable or where in. but this would be a very slow process considering the search happen with every page post back.

Would it be possible to filter out the result in code behind during gridview.databinding?
or its datasource databinding?

Comment: you could use entity framework to pull the data to the C# side and then slap them together, but I doubt that it is going to do it more efficently than the DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I Don't use the mark up page Datasource, I use a DataTable in code behind.
Fill datatable with a standard sqlcommand and sqldatareader. 
Then while datareader.read I skip rows for which UI does'nt match list of "good" UI from DB2. 
Then Bind GridView to Data table.
It even works with gridview paging which i was not expecting to.